# Which files are required in the PHP API library

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

The [PHP API library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases) is around 15MB. I'm only using the calendar API so which folders do I need to keep and which can I remove in order to reduce the overall size?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no sample or tutorial that will guide you to download only the specific file/s for the PHP client library. You can try using Javascript, which only requires you to link the `api.js` and perform authorization to use Google APIs. See [sample code](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js), to see some code implementation for using Google APIs on Javascript. Hope this helps.